# Modifying display object property in Corona sSk

Tags: coronasdk

I am doing my first game in Corona SDK and I've been stuck for a while. I am trying to move two display objects, every object has a position property, after every move I update the position property, the problem is if I click again the object it don't show me the updated position.

I created my objects this way:

```
while count<=16 do
    button[count] = display.newImage(count..".png")
    button[count].position = count
    count = count+1
end
```

And in my touch handler listener I want to move object 1 and 2:

```
local c = 1
while c <= 2 do
    --HERE I DO THE MOVEMENT, THIS WORKS
    transition.to( button[c], { time=200, delta=true, x=100 } )

    --HERE I CHANGE THE POSITION
    button[c].position = 1000
    c = c+1
end
```

Then if I click again any of the 2 objects the position property was not updated! Thank you!

Comment: You are hard coding the position property as '1000'. Then how it will get updated..? :O
And, if you want to change the position of the object, then pls use button[c].x and button[c].y properties. :)

Comment: Yes, the 1000 is for testing purposes only, but when I check the objects position again I don't see that 1000, I see the old value

Comment: why do you use delta=true ?

Comment: Can u provide further more code/details where you are printing the position property values...